# Server isn't responding via HTTP

Tags: rest, ignite

Ignite 2.15.0, Java 1.8, Mac OS X 10.16, ignite-rest-http module added in pom.

When starting server node we see

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @3560ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.44.v20210927; built: 2021-09-27T23:02:44.612Z; git: 8da83308eeca865e495e53ef315a249d63ba9332; jvm 1.8.0_162-b12
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@3976ebfa{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:9999}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @3882ms
```

But response to http://127.0.0.1:9999/ignite?cmd=version is socket hang up (or ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in browser).
Port 9999 is free for Ignite and in LISTEN state (netstat -tna).

We tried to set different IGNITE_JETTY_HOST, IGNITE_JETTY_PORT and IGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true but useless.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Ignite uses Jetty to provide HTTP server features. So, you also need to configure the Jetty.

To get more information please follow the [link](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/restapi#example-jetty-xml-configuration)

Comment: We set `ConnectorConfiguration.setJettyPath("jetty.xml")` where jetty.xml is [link](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/restapi#example-jetty-xml-configuration) without any change. Server starts but still no response.

Comment: If you use standard log config for apache ignite packages, you can either disable quiet mode by using  -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or check log files and try to find lines like these
[17:59:24,087][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Remote Management [restart: on, REST: on, JMX (remote: off)]
...
[17:59:25,395][INFO][main][GridJettyRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully started [name=Jetty REST, host=/0.0.0.0, port=8080]
...
>>> Local ports: TCP:8080 TCP:10800 TCP:11211 TCP:47100 UDP:47400 TCP:47500
It can help you identify if the configured REST port is exposed.

Comment: Log output is `>>> Local node addresses: [prg-1/127.0.0.1, /192.168.1.150]
>>> Local ports: TCP:9999 TCP:10800 TCP:11211 TCP:47100 TCP:47500` We also try `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`. Still have same problem.